# Changing row in Excel file when row is filled

Tags: python, excel, tkinter, row, openpyxl

[image]

I'm coding a simple timer using Tkinter. I want my code to save the time the timer is showing when the stop button is activated in an Excel file. The timer works fine but the data is stored in just one row in the Excel file. I want it to change row when e.g. 5 cells in a row is filled.

I've been trying using conditional `for` loop. E.G. I tried to increment `min_row` with 1 every time the cell values is `not None` but it's not working.

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
# ***** IMPORTS *****
import tkinter as tk
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook



running = False
# time variables initially set to 0
hours, minutes, seconds, total_time = 0, 0, 0, 0

def start():
    global running
    if not running:
        update()
        running = True

# pause function
def pause():
    global running
    if running:
        # cancel updating of time using after_cancel()
        stopwatch_label.after_cancel(update_time)
        running = False

# reset function
def reset():
    global running
    if running:
        # cancel updating of time using after_cancel()
        stopwatch_label.after_cancel(update_time)
        running = False
    # set variables back to zero
    global hours, minutes, seconds
    hours, minutes, seconds = 0, 0, 0
    # set label back to zero
    stopwatch_label.config(text='00:00:00')

# update stopwatch function
def update():
    # update seconds with (addition) compound assignment operator
    global hours, minutes, seconds, total_time
    seconds += 1
    total_time += 1
    if seconds == 60:
        minutes += 1
        seconds = 0
    if minutes == 60:
        hours += 1
        minutes = 0
    # format time to include leading zeros
    hours_string = f'{hours}' if hours > 9 else f'0{hours}'
    minutes_string = f'{minutes}' if minutes > 9 else f'0{minutes}'
    seconds_string = f'{seconds}' if seconds > 9 else f'0{seconds}'
    # update timer label after 1000 ms (1 second)
    stopwatch_label.config(text=hours_string + ':' + minutes_string + ':' + seconds_string)

    global update_time
    update_time = stopwatch_label.after(1000, update)
    
def excel_update():
    dest_filename = r"C:\Users\abbas\OneDrive\Desktop\Prog\Flex\tider.xlsx"
    #dest_filename = r"C:\Users\abbas\OneDrive\Desktop\Prog\Flex\test.xlsx"
    wb = load_workbook(dest_filename)
    ws = wb.active
    next_row = 1
    
    cell_range = ws.iter_rows(min_row=next_row, max_row=3, max_col=2)
    #cell_range = ws["A1":"B3"]
    
    for rows in cell_range:        
        for columns in rows:
            if columns.value[columns] is None:
                columns.value[columns] = total_time
                          
        break
    
    wb.save(dest_filename)   
    
# ***** WIDGETS *****
# create main window
root = tk.Tk()
#root.geometry('450x200')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.title('Stopwatch')

# label to display time
stopwatch_label = tk.Label(text='00:00:00', font=('Arial', 20))
stopwatch_label.pack()

# start, pause, reset, stop buttons
start_button = tk.Button(text='start', height=3, width=5, font=('Arial', 10), command=start)
start_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

stop_button = tk.Button(text='stop', height=3, width=5, font=('Arial', 10), command=lambda:[root.quit(), excel_update()])
stop_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

pause_button = tk.Button(text='pause', height=3, width=5, font=('Arial', 10), command=pause)
pause_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

reset_button = tk.Button(text='reset', height=3, width=5, font=('Arial', 10), command=reset)
reset_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

# ***** MAINLOOP *****
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you want to just put the `total_time` value in one cell in the worksheet when the stop button is clicked, or all of them in the range that aren't `None`?

Comment: Just in one cell and when the rows is filled (the cells in the row is limited since I choose e.g min_cols=1 and max_cols=5) I don't want the row to expand into infinity. The reason is that I'm trying to log the times in a fancy excel calendar and use it at my work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code in your updated question, I think changing the `excel_update()` function as shown below will make it do what you want.

It searches through the columns of the rows from `min_row` to `max_row` looking for an empty `cell`. If it finds one it assigns the time value to it and raises a `StopIteration` exception to break out of the nested `for` loops and terminate the search. The exception is then simply ignored since it's part of normal processing.

```
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror

def excel_update():
def excel_update():
    dest_filename = r"C:\Users\abbas\OneDrive\Desktop\Prog\Flex\tider.xlsx"
    wb = load_workbook(dest_filename)
    ws = wb.active

    # Put value in next empty cell in specified region (if one exists).
    try:
        for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=3, max_col=3):
            for cell in row:
                if cell.value is None:
                    cell.value = total_time
                    raise StopIteration
        else:  # No exception raised.
            showerror('Error!', 'No empty cells left for storing timer time!')
    except StopIteration:
        pass

    wb.save(dest_filename)  # Update file.
```

Comment: Thanks for you'r response!

I understand that the inne loop terminated when break is stated. If I remove break then all cells in the given range in a specific column is overwritten. I want the value in individual cells to be replaced with the time the timer shows when the stop button is pressed. 

The same applies when the break in the outer loop is absent, then all the cells in a specific row is overwritten by the time the timer shows. 

What I want is, when e.g 5 cells in a row is filled, to change row. E.g f´change from row 2 to 3.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. I suggest you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72005204/edit) your question and put something in it showing the data before and after such a change was made. You also need to identify what module you are using to read and write Excel files with.

Comment: Hello Sir!

Now I've uploaded the codes. I appreciate any help  since I've been struggling with this for a while now.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works just as I want. And I understand my mistake